# How to convert Microsoft Graph dateTimeTimeZone to local DateTime?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) the `datetime` values (for example in events of outlook) are returned as an instance of [DateTimeTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0) class. This object is composed by two properties ( datetime and timezone ) that are strings, and represents a UTC date. In a `UWP` app, we can control how those values are displayed by using a `value converter` as follows:

**Question**: The [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-19041) Interface used in the following code is from a `UWP` [Windows.UI.Xaml.Data](http://Windows.UI.Xaml.Data%20Namespace) Namespace. How can we achieve the same in a `WPF` app?

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;

class GraphDateTimeTimeZoneConverter : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            DateTimeTimeZone date = value as DateTimeTimeZone;

            if (date != null)
            {
                // Resolve the time zone
                var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(date.TimeZone);
                // Parse method assumes local time, which may not be the case
                var parsedDateAsLocal = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date.DateTime);
                // Determine the offset from UTC time for the specific date
                // Making this call adjusts for DST as appropriate
                var tzOffset = timezone.GetUtcOffset(parsedDateAsLocal.DateTime);
                // Create a new DateTimeOffset with the specific offset from UTC
                var correctedDate = new DateTimeOffset(parsedDateAsLocal.DateTime, tzOffset);
                // Return the local date time string
                return correctedDate.LocalDateTime.ToString();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**UWP Xaml**:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyMSGraphProject.CalendarPage"
   ....
</Page>

<Page.Resources>
    <local:GraphDateTimeTimeZoneConverter x:Key="DateTimeTimeZoneValueConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
  <DataGrid x:Name="EventList" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birth Date" Binding="{Binding BirthDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeTimeZoneValueConverter}}" />
      .....
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Snapshot of the display of the above DataGrid**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF has the very similar [`System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter).

This documentation explains how to add references to the UWP libraries from a Windows Desktop application: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

Using the above, you can create a `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter` which references the `DateTimeTimeZone` type and does the appropriate conversion, just like your current `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter` does.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). Adding
`using System.Globalization; using System.Windows.Data;` to the code in my post above, and replacing the input parameter `string language` with `CultureInfo language` did the trick.